# With SDCC, how to access word pointer from another file

Tags: c, sdcc

I'm using SDCC compiler for a microcontroller.

In tunes.c, I declare an integer table:

```
__code unsigned int Beep1[] = {4, 0, 1500, 750, 375};

void PlayTune(unsigned int Addr[])
{ /* code */ }
```

In main.c, I play the tune:

```
PlayTune(Beep1)
```

In tunes.h, my function is declared.

```
void PlayTune(unsigned int Addr[]);
```

Still in tunes.h, how do i declare Beep1 so that I can access it from main.c

```
__code unsigned int Beep1[]; /* compiler not happy */
__code unsigned int *Beep1; /* compiler still not happy */
```

Comment: `extern` maybe ?

Comment: You need to declare `extern unsigned int Beep1[];` in main.c. With you declarations the _compiler_ is happy, but the _linker_ is not.